# On the differentiability of $\frac{\sin(x^2)+\cos(y^2)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$

Tags: derivatives

Does this function $f:\mathbb{R^2}\to\mathbb{R}$ defined by:
$$\frac{\sin(x^2)+\cos(y^2)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$$
differentiable at the origin? Thank you

Comment: The function doesn't seem to be defined at the origin, for instance, if you set $ y = 0 $ then it blows up as $ x \rightarrow 0 $.

Comment: Then we can't calculate partial derivative at the origin?

Comment: Right, if a function isn't defined at $ x $, then its derivative isn't defined at $ x $ either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function
$$
f(x) = \frac{\sin \left(x^2\right)+\cos \left(y^2\right)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}
$$
is **not differentiable** at the origin.

---

The iterated limit demonstrates the problem.

$$
\begin{align}
 \lim_{\color{red}{x}\to 0} f(x,y) &= \frac{\cos \left(y^2\right)}{\sqrt{y^2}} \\[3pt]
 \lim_{\color{blue}{y}\to 0} \left( \lim_{\color{red}{x}\to 0} f(x,y) \right) &= \infty \\
\end{align}
$$

---

$$
\begin{align}
 \lim_{\color{blue}{y}\to 0} f(x,y) &= \frac{\sin \left(x^2\right)+1}{\sqrt{x^2}} \\[3pt]
 \lim_{\color{red}{x}\to 0} \left( \lim_{\color{blue}{y}\to 0} f(x,y) \right) &= \infty \\
\end{align}
$$

---

The function is growing rapidly near the origin.

[image: origin]

---

Hint: Maclaurin series

$$  
\sin x^{2} = x^{2} - \frac{x^{2}}{6} + \mathcal{O}\left( x^{8} \right)
$$

Comment: Thanks for this good answer!